# How to write to clipboard on Ubuntu/Linux in R?

Tags: r

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and I would like to be able to write to the clipboard (or primary selection). The following gives an error

```
> x <- 1:10
> dput(x, 'clipboard')
Error in file(file, "wt") : 'mode' for the clipboard must be 'r' on Unix
```

**How can I write to the clipboard/primary selection?**

Note that I have seen [this old R-Help post](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/06/11/4157.html), but I'm still not clear what I should be doing.

> Linux does not have a clipboard but an X11 session has primary and
>   secondary selections. ?file says
>
> Clipboard:
>
> ```
>   'file' can also be used with 'description = "clipboard"' in mode
>   '"r"' only.  It reads the X11 primary selection, which can also be
>   specified as '"X11_primary"' and the secondary selection as
>   '"X11_secondary"'.
>
>   When the clipboard is opened for reading, the contents are
>   immediately copied to internal storage in the connection.
>
>   Unix users wishing to _write_ to the primary selection may be able
>   to do so via 'xclip' (<URL:
>   http://people.debian.org/~kims/xclip/>), for example by
>   'pipe("xclip -i", "w")'.
> ```
>
> so RTFM applied. Writing to an X11 selection needs multiple threads
>   and I did not think it worth the very considerable effort of
>   implementing (unlike for Windows).
>
> Note that window managers may have other clipboards, and for example
>   the RGtk2 package has interfaces to gtk clipboards.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure if this is the *best* way, but here's how I could get it to work:

1. Install xclip: `sudo apt-get install xclip`
2. Read the manual: `man xclip`
3. Write to X11 primary in R: `write.table(1:10, pipe("xclip -i", "w"))`

---

**Update:**

Note that the object passed to `write.table` will not be present in the clipboard until the pipe is closed. You can force the pipe to close by calling `gc()`. For example:

```
write.table(1:10, pipe("xclip -i", "w"))  # data may not be in clipboard
gc()                                      # data written to primary clipboard
```

---

A better way to manage the connection is to use a function with `on.exit(close(con))`, which will close the pipe even if the `write.table` call throws an error. Note that you need to ensure you're writing to the clipboard you intend to use (primary is the default), based on your system setup.

```
write.xclip <- function(x, selection=c("primary", "secondary", "clipboard"), ...) {
  if (!isTRUE(file.exists(Sys.which("xclip")[1L])))
    stop("Cannot find xclip")
  selection <- match.arg(selection)[1L]
  con <- pipe(paste0("xclip -i -selection ", selection), "w")
  on.exit(close(con))
  write.table(x, con, ...)
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. I appreciate it. I'm still interested to see what other strategies exist. The main reason I occasionally like pasting to the clipboard is to save a couple of seconds, instead of writing to a file and copying from the file. The above strategy seems to assume that I can predict ahead of time that I would need the clipboard. I also couldn't get it working in R Studio. I could only get it working with the console.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim I also noticed this was an RStudio issue, so you'd better report to RStudio developers. I do not know what they did with the clipboard.

Comment: This didn't work for me in ubuntu, either in R Studio or in the terminal version of R.  I'll admit that I didn't fully read the man for xclip (step 2), but I don't think that should affect the results.

Comment: Did not work for me either (Linux Mint 18, based on Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: The above didn't work for me in an interactive session, but creating a separate connection variable and then manually calling `close()` on it, as in @Freecube's solution below, did the trick.

Comment: @KeithHughitt: looks like that's because the pipe isn't flushed until the connection is closed. You can force it to close by calling `gc()`, but using a function and `on.exit` is more robust. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Good suggestions! Thanks for taking the time to update answer as well.

Answer (score 26):

```
clipboard <- function(x, sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE){
     con <- pipe("xclip -selection clipboard -i", open="w")
     write.table(x, con, sep=sep, row.names=row.names, col.names=col.names)
     close(con)
}

vec <- c(1,2,3,4)

clipboard(vec)
clipboard(vec, ",", col.names=FALSE)
clipboard(vec, " ", row.names=TRUE)
```

You can paste back anything you write to the clipboard after creating the function as such. Default returns tab separated values with column but no row names. Specify other separators, include row names, or exclude column names to your liking as shown.

Edit: To clarify, you still need to install xclip. You don't need to start it separately first, though.

Answer (score 23):

the clipr package makes this really easy

```
x <- 1:10
clipr::write_clip(x)
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Versions:

- Mint 18.1, Cinnamon
- xclip 0.12
- R 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)

I could not get the other solutions to work, so I `man`ed up. This approach works for me (based on others' solutions).

```
write_clipboard = function(x, .rownames = F) {
    #decide how to write
    #windows is easy!
    if (Sys.info()['sysname'] %in% c("Windows")) {
      #just write as normal
      write.table(x, "clipboard", sep = "\t", na = "", row.names = F)
    } else {
      #for non-windows, try xclip approach
      #https://stackoverflow.com/a/10960498/3980197
      write.xclip = function(x) {
        #if xclip not installed
        if (!isTRUE(file.exists(Sys.which("xclip")[1L]))) {
          stop("Cannot find xclip")
        }
        con <- pipe("xclip -selection c", "w")
        on.exit(close(con))
        write.table(x, con, sep = "\t", na = "", row.names = F)
      }

      tryCatch({
        write.xclip(x)
      }, error = function(e) {
        message("Could not write using xclip")
      })
    }
}
```

It's a watered down version of a function in [my personal R package](https://github.com/Deleetdk/kirkegaard).

## Reading from the clipboard

Reading is equally difficult. Here's a companion function for the above.

```
read_clipboard = function(header = T,
                          sep = "\t",
                          na.strings = c("", "NA"),
                          check.names = T,
                          stringsAsFactors = F,
                          dec = ".",
                          ...) {
  #decide how to read
  #windows is easy!
  if (Sys.info()['sysname'] %in% c("Windows")) {
    #just read as normal
    read.table(file = con, sep = sep, header = header, check.names = check.names, na.strings = na.strings, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors, dec = dec, ...)
  } else {
    #for non-windows, try xclip approach
    #https://stackoverflow.com/a/10960498/3980197
    read.xclip = function(x) {
      #if xclip not installed
      if (!isTRUE(file.exists(Sys.which("xclip")[1L]))) {
        stop("Cannot find xclip")
      }
      con <- pipe("xclip -o -selection c", "r")
      on.exit(close(con))
      read.table(file = con, sep = sep, header = header, check.names = check.names, na.strings = na.strings, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors, dec = dec, ...)
    }

    tryCatch({
      read.xclip(x)
    }, error = function(e) {
      message(sprintf("error: %s", e$message))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Now we're talking!! Totally using this in my package (geneorama/geneorama) and looking at yours more

Comment: Also, love that you have a .rownames argument, but then hardcode rownames to false.  Probably because nobody in their right mind would ever want them for anything.

Comment: Pretty funny, no one noticed that bug before.