# R: cat data to buffer instead to console screen

Tags: r, buffer

I would like to `cat` data to buffer, so I can copy them using `CTRL + V` command. Now they get prinded to screen, from which I have to copy them manually. I know how to print to file in `R`, but it is not suitable for my purposes.

Comment: Are you lloking for `writeClipboard` ? (Windows only)

Comment: I am using Linux, so that will not do

Comment: Then maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959521/how-to-write-to-clipboard-on-ubuntu-linux-in-r) will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way, as indicated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959521/how-to-write-to-clipboard-on-ubuntu-linux-in-r) and reported by @etienne, is to use the linux utility `xclip`. The `clipr` package wraps it and make it easy to use. It provides the intuitive `read_clip` and `write_clip` functions. For instance, you can try:

```
require(clipr)
write_clip(letters[1:10],breaks="")
```

and write:

```
abcdefghij
```

with CTRL+V.

Important notice: you can install `clipr` without `xclip`, but it will be basically useless.