# Copy-to-clipboard and downloadhandler not working when Shiny App deployed on Ubuntu server

Tags: r, shiny, clipboard

I developed my Shiny apps in Windows. All features (including copy-to-clipboard and download buttons) work as expected.

However, when I deploy it in our AWS Server (ubuntu), the copy-to-clipboard and download buttons fail.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
shiny::observeEvent(input$copy_cross, {
clipr::write_clip(eval(parse(text = "x = as.data.frame.matrix(table(sel()[,1],sel()[,2]))")), row.names= T, col.names = NA)
})

output$download_cross <- shiny::downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {paste("Crosstabs (Counts).xlsx")},
  content  = function(file) {
    openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = as.data.frame.matrix(table(sel()[,1],sel()[,2])), file, sheetName = "Crosstabs", row.names= T, col.names = T, append=F)
  }
)
```

I also tried using xclip as suggested in this article
[How to write to clipboard on Ubuntu/Linux in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959521/how-to-write-to-clipboard-on-ubuntu-linux-in-r). However, it's also not working.

Comment: Double check the installation of `openxlsx` in your server.

Comment: Anything in particular I should be paying attention to?

Comment: Did you get any specific message after running `sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages(c('open'xlsx), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""`? Also, make sure that you are calling `library(openxlsx)` at the beginning of your script.