# How to assign the output of dput() into an object or insert the double quote and then comma after every words?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, dput

I have a data frame like that:

```
x <- data.table(c('ACCN-NJ-A55O-01A-11D-A25L-08','ACCN-NJ-A55O-11D-11D-A25L-08', 'ACCN-05-4249-01A-01D-1105-08', 'ACCN-S2-AA1A-15C-12D-A397-08'))
```

Now I want to put every word inside the double quote and then place a comma. I tried dput, cat, paste, etc but they return print instead of assigning to an object. I need to assign it to an object for copying it to the clipboard. I tried dput and dget

```
dput( x$V1, "names")
xx <- dget("names")
xxxx <- cat(paste0('"', paste(xx, collapse="\", \""), '"'))
```

It return the expected output like

```
"ACCN-NJ-A55O-01A-11D-A25L-08", "ACCN-NJ-A55O-11D-11D-A25L-08", "ACCN-05-4249-01A-01D-1105-08", "ACCN-S2-AA1A-15C-12D-A397-08"
```

but I want to assign it into an object.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write.table to clipboard works.

```
    write.table(t(as.vector(x)), "clipboard", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

then ctrl+V to script returns

```
    "ACCN-NJ-A55O-01A-11D-A25L-08","ACCN-NJ-A55O-11D-11D-A25L-08","ACCN-05-4249-01A-01D-1105-08","ACCN-S2-AA1A-15C-12D-A397-08"
```

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much but it return error "Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  'mode' for the clipboard must be 'r' on Unix". Earlier I was also getting the same error with the clipboard so I use xclip

Comment: clipboard <- function(x, sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE){
  con <- pipe("xclip -selection clipboard -i", open="w")
  write.table(x, con, sep=sep, row.names=row.names, 
              col.names=col.names)
  close(con)
}
clipboard(x)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959521/how-to-write-to-clipboard-on-ubuntu-linux-in-r

this link may be helpful

Comment: That is for xclip. would you modify the code and assign the output to an object?  Afterward I will do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you working on LINUX? 
        clip <- pipe("pbcopy", "w")  \                     
        write.table(t(as.vector(x)), file=clip)         \                      
        close(clip) \
I'll apologize that it is hard to understand your error status or situation.

Comment: Yes it is in linux. it retrun the error Error: unexpected '\\' in "clip <- pipe("pbcopy", "w") \"

Comment: this comment place doesn't allow changing the line, if I understand error message you've got. Would you try that code again with out \'s? Code has three lines,  > clip <- pipe("pbcopy", "w") >write.table(t(as.vector(x)), file=clip)  >close(clip). Thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am sorry dear, dear first line     clip <- pipe("pbcopy", "w") return error      sh: 1: pbcopy: not found     any idea? why

Comment: I'll try with LINUX and then reply later. My apologies

Comment: Thank you, dear. It's OK I am not going to give trouble, I will work around the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use -

```
val <- sprintf('"%s"', x$V1)
val

#[1] "\"ACCN-NJ-A55O-01A-11D-A25L-08\"" "\"ACCN-NJ-A55O-11D-11D-A25L-08\""
#[3] "\"ACCN-05-4249-01A-01D-1105-08\"" "\"ACCN-S2-AA1A-15C-12D-A397-08\""
```

Note that R escapes `"` hence you see the quotes with backslash. The "real" string can be seen with `cat`.

```
cat(val)

"ACCN-NJ-A55O-01A-11D-A25L-08" "ACCN-NJ-A55O-11D-11D-A25L-08" 
"ACCN-05-4249-01A-01D-1105-08" "ACCN-S2-AA1A-15C-12D-A397-08"
```

If you want the output to be of length one comma-separated string use `toString(val)`.

Comment: Thank you dear sir, but AFAK cat is the print function, I cannot assign to df <- cat(val). Yes R escapes ". Actually, I have 1000s of files which I need to move to another dir. Since I cannot copy the whole cat/dput output beyond the moniter in rstudio so I thought to assign it to an object, copy that object to clip, and paste it another object filestocopy file.copy(from=filestocopy, to=targetdir, copy.mode = TRUE)

Comment: Its OK if it is not possible, I am doing it by dividing the all files into 100-100 files and then via dupt i am trying to move

Comment: `cat` doesn't return any value. It returns `NULL`. If you want to move files use `list.files` to get the path of the files and pass the path directly to `file.copy`.

Comment: I need to filter the list.files based condition and then trying to move the selected file, I tried your suggestion but return character(0)

Comment: Brother its OK I am accepting the answer and closing it. My process taking time but its ok. I don't want to waste your precious time. Thanks